# PHP: Non static method called as it was static, how is that possible?

Tags: php

is there anyway to call a non static method, as an static method?

I have found this call:

```
$handler =& ProfileHandler_Array::getInstance(
    array(  'username'        => $this->api_username,
            'certificateFile' => $this->api_certificate,
            'signature'       => $this->api_signature,
            'subject'         => $this->api_subject,
            'environment'     => (($this->api_test)?'Sandbox':'Live')
    )
```

And here you have getInstance() method:

```
function getInstance($id, &$handler)
{
    $classname = __CLASS__;
    $inst = new $classname($id, $handler);

    $result = $inst->_load();
    if (PayPal::isError($result)) {
        return $result;
    }

    $result = $inst->loadEnvironments();
    if (PayPal::isError($result)) {
        return $result;
    }

    return $inst;
}
```

and it doesn't give any errors!!!!

More clues: it's maybe an old code.

Regards

Comment: When you use `error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_STRICT);` do you get errors?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does static method in PHP have any difference with non-static method ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2439036/does-static-method-in-php-have-any-difference-with-non-static-method)

Answer (score 2):

Your code should give an error, it just isn't displayed. (Is `error_reporting` set to `E_ALL | E_STRICT`? Is `display_errors` enabled?)

From [the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php):

> Calling non-static methods statically generates an `E_STRICT` level warning.