# PHP: calling non-static methods with scope resolution operator

Tags: php, scope-resolution

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Calling non static method with "::"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3754786/calling-non-static-method-with)
>   [Does static method in PHP have any difference with non-static method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2439036/does-static-method-in-php-have-any-difference-with-non-static-method)

What is the reason for allowing calling non-static methods using ::, given we don't try to access anything inside the object context with $this? Is it a backward compatibility thing, or is it so for some particular reason? Should I get myself used to avoiding using :: to access non-static methods?

```
class Foo{    
public function Bar(){
    echo "this works just fine"; 
    }
}

Foo::Bar();
```

Comment: more http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=calling+non-static+method+statically+php

Answer (score -1):

There are several reasons why someone might do this.

- One is that a function may live in a class and may not depend on the class being instantiated to produce results and you may not be able to instantiate the class or it is a heavy instantiation so you just call the function.
- It is needed to load a singleton.
- It is helpful in Factory pattern classes
- Maybe someone just wants to group related functions together rather than just use a naming convention for all the functions
- can access methods in an abstract class if needed
- I'm sure there is much more

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-php-designptrns/