# Accessing private variable in PHP ( PDO)

Tags: php, mysql, string, pdo

I am using PDO in PHP ... I have the following problem.

The following code does not work.

```
class A {
 private $getUsersQuery = "SELECT * FROM users";      
 ...
 public function getUsers() {       
   $DBH = A::getDatabaseConnection();           
   try {
      $query = $DBH->prepare($this->getUsersQuery); 
      ...
   } catch(PDOException $e) {}
 }
}
```

But if I use the string it works.

```
$DBH->prepare("SELECT * FROM users");
```

Even if I use the echo outside the prepare() it works ...

```
echo $this->getUsersQuery;   // Outputs the sql string.
```

Can someone point out what the problem might be.

Update :

Error :

SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1065 Query was empty

Thanks

Comment: This should work fine. Check your code carefully for typos.

Comment: Agreed it should work. What exactly do you mean by 'does not work'? Any error message?

Comment: The most important question here is: How does it NOT work? What error message to you get, etc.?

Comment: Your code looks Ok. why did you say it's not working?

Comment: Well, I wouldn't say the code looks perfect but we really need to know what errors you get.

Comment: I get the following error SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1065 Query was empty ... But echo $this->getUsersQuery; shows the query string..

Comment: how do you call getUsers() ?

Comment: try-catch blocks are just useful if you are doing something with the exception (i. e. output the error message to a file). if you are using it to hide error messages you will never know why your code not work.

Comment: @Dr.Molle I call getUsers() from another class like this $results = A::getUsers();

Comment: what kind of database handle do you get? may be the method prepare gets a reference (i. e.: public function prepare(&$query) {...}) and the reference is not accessible for the database handle class.

Comment: @iRaS I think the DB handle works fine coz ... $DBH->prepare("SELECT * FROM users");  does not give me any problem.

Comment: so you call a non static method statically? the instance variable is not available in there. you have to create an instance of A:
"$a = new A(); $a->getUsers();" i always tell my team members they should enable strict warnings for development environment just because you can see your errors.

Comment: How did this even pass parsing? If you a calling a non-static member function without an object? Something is very funky with this question.

Comment: thats right. i just tried this (does i remember correctly?). you have to get a fatal error: Using $this when not in object context

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentionned in your comment, you make a static call to a method that is not static.

Using `$this` in a method that is called like this makes no sense:

```
$results = A::getUsers();
```

Instanciate your class, and then call the method on the class object.

```
$a = new A();
$a->getUsers();
```

Or make your method and SQL query static.

Comment: How did the original code even parse?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit It seems that the OP stated otherwise :P But I do understand your point. I know that somehow PHP doesn't seem to care when you statically call a non static method, and most of the times will throw a warning but execute the code anyway. So why did it work with an `echo` and not in a method parameter is a mystery to me.

Comment: @MathieuImbert: [Holy heck](http://ideone.com/iXz0Nn). What a sorry state of affairs...

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Yes I've noticed that in production while cleaning the error logs. My guess is that a simple `echo` PHP will just *convert* the non static variable to a static one. But in the case of a parameter, it needs to get a reference of it and fails.

Comment: @MathieuImbert even the call to $this when called statically should throw a fatal error. at least in my php version (5.3.10)

Comment: @iRaS It seems that this issue was discussed before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2439036/does-static-method-in-php-have-any-difference-with-non-static-method

Comment: @MathieuImbert alright, thanks - that was new to me. so it is an object of class A that is is calling A::getUsers(). very complicated to debug, uh?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$a = new A();
$result = $a->getUsers();
```

The value of $getUsersQuery was probably not initialized when you called A::getUsers(). Static methods are called liked that.